# R: dplyr::filter & base::`[` unable to deal with column type ts

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to `filter` rows (in `dplyr` parlance) from an R `data.frame`, and am running into problems using both `` base::`[` `` and `dplyr::filter`. Here is an example:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

dfTest = data.frame(dates = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2014-01-01"),
                                     to = as.Date("2014-03-01"), by = "day"), 
                    someNum1 = seq(1, 60, 1), 
                    someNum2 = rnorm(60))

# mutate one of the columns to give it type 'ts'
dfTest = dfTest %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(someNum2F = stats::filter(someNum2, c(0.1), "recursive"))
class(dfTest$someNum2F)

# try to filter with dplyr::filter
dfTest1 = dfTest %>% 
  dplyr::filter(dates >= as.Date("2014-02-01")) # Error: cannot deal with "ts" type columns

# try to filter with base::`[`
class(dfTest$someNum2F)
dfTest2 = dfTest[dfTest$dates >= as.Date(2014-02-01), ]
class(dfTest2$someNum2F)
```

Note that `dplyr::filter` chokes on the column type, and `` base::`[` `` quietly changes the column type to `numeric`. This does not seem like desirable behavior to me.

Can someone suggest a correct method to filter rows of a `data.frame` without changing the column types?

Another question would be why the behavior of the functions is this way.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the reason for the change in behavior, perhaps the `ts` after subsetting needs to change the series from `from 1:60` to `from 1:29`.  You may modify it later `dfTest2[,4] <- as.ts(dfTest2[,4])`, but I don't know if this helps for you

Comment: @akrun That makes sense as an explanation -- thanks. Not sure if expecting this behavior then makes sense. As an aside, note that `base::subset` has the same behavior as ``base::`[` ``, as expected.

Comment: `subset` is a convenience function of `[`.  It is useful with default options like `drop=FALSE`.  According to `?subset`. `This is a convenience function intended for use interactively.
     For programming it is better to use the standard subsetting
     functions like ‘[’, and in particular the non-standard evaluation
     of argument ‘subset’ can have unanticipated consequences.`

Comment: @akrun Hence, "as expected". :-)

Answer (score 1):

If we check the `methods` for `[`

```
 methods(`[`)[51]
 #[1] "[.ts"
```

According to the description in `?ts`

> Class ‘"ts"’ has a number of methods.  In particular arithmetic
>        will attempt to align time axes, and subsetting to extract subsets
>        of series can be used (e.g., ‘EuStockMarkets[, "DAX"]’).  However,
>        subsetting the first (or only) dimension will return a matrix or
>        vector, as will matrix subsetting.  Subassignment can be used to
>        replace values but not to extend a series (see ‘window’).  There
>        is a method for ‘t’ that transposes the series as a matrix (a
>        one-column matrix if a vector) and hence returns a result that
>        does not inherit from class ‘"ts"’.

One option would be to reconvert to `ts` class after we subset with `[`.  As noted in the error, the `dplyr` may not support the `ts` class.

```
 dfTest2 <- dfTest[dfTest$dates >= as.Date('2014-02-01'), ]
 str(dfTest2)
 #'data.frame': 29 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ dates    : Date, format: "2014-02-01" "2014-02-02" ...
 #$ someNum1 : num  32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 ...
 #$ someNum2 : num  0.423 -1.673 -1.136 0.361 1.057 ...
 #$ someNum2F: num  0.365 -1.637 -1.3 0.231 1.08 ...

 dfTest2[,4] <- as.ts(dfTest2[,4])
 str(dfTest2)
 #'data.frame': 29 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ dates    : Date, format: "2014-02-01" "2014-02-02" ...
 #$ someNum1 : num  32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 ...
 #$ someNum2 : num  0.423 -1.673 -1.136 0.361 1.057 ...
 #$ someNum2F: Time-Series  from 1 to 29: 0.365 -1.637 -1.3 0.231 1.08 ...
```